# Basic troubles with python maths

Tags: python, math

Working on a very simple program to learn python.

The goal is to calculate Euler's constant with the user inputing a value for the equations precision (p). The program should use that variable in the equation (1+1/p)^(10^p).

I am currently having two problems with this program. The first of which is that the program will work if I first define p as p=10**p, then use the equation (1+1/p)**p which brings us to the second problem.

The second problem is that any (user inputted) value for p that exceeds 14 will not work at all. (15 returns 3.035035... and higher values just return 1.0)

I am extremely new to python and its math syntax and that may be my problem.

Thank you all for any help

Code in question:

```py
import math
p=None
e=None

p = int(input('Please enter a whole number precison multiplier (1-14):'))

p=10.0**p

print((1.0+1.0/p)**p)
```

Comment: You've changed the value of `p` in `p=10.0**p` so the second half of your calculation is wrong. Use a new, intermediate variable to hold this value and use it in the second half.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to approximate e. The formula is (1 + 1/p)^p as p -> infinity, not (1 + 1/p)^(10^p). This should work:

```
p = int(input('Please enter a whole number precison multiplier:'))
print((1 + 1/p)**(p))
```